# OutofMemory Exception When Debugging Game

Tags: c#, xna, xna-4.0

I've been successfully creating a game so far in XNA and have run into the following error when I attempted to debug

```
spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);
```

The error that was recieved from Output is this

```
'Duality.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Duality.exe): Loaded  'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.dll' Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
A first chance exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' occurred in Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics.dll

Unhandled Exception: OutOfMemoryException.
```

Here's also any references to `SpriteBatch`. These are in different parts of the file, not all in the same area

```
//Outside of all Methods
SpriteBatch spriteBatch;
//In Draw Method
spriteBatch.Begin();
        /*spriteBatch.Draw(cursorTex, cursorPos, Color.White);*/
        spriteBatch.End();
        base.Draw(gameTime);
 spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.BackToFront, BlendState.AlphaBlend);
 base.Draw(gameTime);
        //The updating the mouse state
        cursorPos = new Vector2(mouseState.X, mouseState.Y);
        cursorPos = new Vector2();
        spriteBatch.End();
```

Comment: Are you properly disposing of all objects? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.graphics.spritebatch.dispose.aspx

Comment: Could be that you have a memory leak or the spritebatch is too big to fit in memory. Although that last part seems unlikely.

Comment: Try eliminating the first `base.Draw(gameTime)`, which is outside any `spriteBatch` Begin/End block. Also, try separating update code from drawing code. Move the `cursorPos` updates in the `Update` method. It most likely won't solve your problem, but it's good habit to keep code separated and clean.

Comment: @Alex what's a memory leak and how do I fix that?

Comment: Also, always try to avoid creating a new object every time the update or draw method is called. In your case, the `cursorPos` should be updated without recreating it. Just set the properties separately to those of the `mouseState`. That should fix your problem.